# PHP combine arrays on same level

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-3.0

So, I am sending data from View to Controller and need to save all (multiple) data in DB.

in view I am using `category[]`, `status_number[]` and `name[]` to collect data, then I got this:

```
[
    'category' => [
        (int) 0 => 'c',
        (int) 1 => 'c1',
        (int) 2 => 'c2'
    ],
    'status_number' => [
        (int) 0 => 'sn',
        (int) 1 => 'sn1',
        (int) 2 => 'sn2'
    ],
    'name' => [
        (int) 0 => 'n',
        (int) 1 => 'n1',
        (int) 2 => 'n2'
    ]
]
```

now I need to transform (combine) this array so that I can store it to DB in this structure

```
[
    '(int) 0' => [
        category => 'c',
        status_number => 'sn',
        name => 'n'
    ],
   '(int) 1' => [
        category => 'c1',
        status_number => 'sn1',
        name => 'n1'
    ],
   '(int) 2' => [
        category => 'c2',
        status_number => 'sn2',
        name => 'n2'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Are you sure with such key names `'(int) 0'`..`'(int) 2'`? I think there should be simple numeric keys.

Comment: That is not so important (naming), I just want to "transform" arrays that I have right data for mass-input in DB

Comment: Why not set up the fields in your input form so that the data is formatted correctly right away?

Comment: @GregSchmidt how do you mean? I am already sending input like defined field ex. category like <input type="text" name="category[]" /> etc. like result I can see that defined inputs, but only structure of data is not appropriate for saving in DB

Comment: Without seeing your existing view code, it's hard to say what would be appropriate for you, but if you use something like `0.category` and `0.status_number` and up to `2.name` then the data you receive should already have the format you're looking for. See the manual section on [creating inputs for associated data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
<?php

$array = [
    'category' => [
        'c',
        'c1',
        'c2'
    ],
    'status_number' => [
        'sn',
        'sn1',
        'sn2'
    ],
    'name' => [
        'n',
        'n1',
        'n2'
    ]
];

$result = [];

array_walk($array, function($data, $key) use (&$result){

    foreach($data as $numericKey => $value) {
        $result[$numericKey][$key] = $value;
    }

});

print_r($result);
```

As the result it gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => c
            [status_number] => sn
            [name] => n
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [category] => c1
            [status_number] => sn1
            [name] => n1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [category] => c2
            [status_number] => sn2
            [name] => n2
        )

)
```